# Why is that the fourth Veda is not mentioned in the Manu Smriti?

Tags: vedas, smriti

While I was reading the Manu Smriti I came across a verse in chapter 1 which reads:

> 23. From out of (the three deities) Agni, Vāyu and Ravi, he extracted, for the due fulfilment of sacrifices, the eternal Brahman, threefold, in the forms of ‘Ṛk,’ ‘Yajuṣ’ and ‘Sāman.’

So seeing this verse and other verses which didn't mention the Atharva Veda. I wanted to ask why is it that the Atharva Veda is not in mentioned in this verse or other verses in the Manu Smriti?

Comment: The verse is not mentioning about 3 Vedas .. it is mentioning about the 3 types of Vedic Mantras -- Rik, Yajus and Saman. All Vedic mantras fall under one of these type. Even Atharva Veda is comprised of some Riks and some Yajus.

Comment: @Rickross oh thanks